# To search for a number in a column and return all the corresponding row elements immediately greater than search number C# in

Tags: c#, xml

```
 <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><Data ss:Type="String">value1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><Data ss:Type="String">value2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><Data ss:Type="String">value3</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><Data ss:Type="String">B</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><Data ss:Type="Number">31</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><Data ss:Type="Number">47</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s19"><Data ss:Type="Number">148</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><Data ss:Type="String">C</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><Data ss:Type="Number">40</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><Data ss:Type="Number">78</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s19"><Data ss:Type="Number">312</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
```

This is my xlm. I want to search the double threshold in value3 column, if value of threshold is 200,  want to return the rows of immediate greater value to threshold in value3 column.(C,40,78,312) in separate variables. I am also have a few warnings, Dereference of a possibly null reference, Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type. how to solve this. this is the code used. any help?

```
     XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(Properties.Resources.Data);double threshold=200;


    
            XmlNodeList rows = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Row[Cell[4][number(Data) > " + threshold +       "]]");
    
            foreach (XmlNode row in rows)
            {
                XmlNodeList cells = row.SelectNodes("Cell/Data");
    
                string cell1 = cells[0].InnerText;
                double cell2 = double.Parse(cells[1].InnerText);
                double cell3 = double.Parse(cells[2].InnerText);
    
            }
```

Comment: your xml is not valid

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq.  I read xml into a datatable and then searched the table

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("B", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("C", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("D", typeof(int));
            object[] row = new object[4];
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            foreach (XElement xRow in doc.Descendants("Row"))
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (XElement cell in xRow.Descendants("Data"))
                {
                    if(index == 0)
                    {
                        row[index] = (string)cell;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row[index] = (int)cell;
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<int>("D")).CopyToDataTable();

            int threshhold = 200;
            DataRow results = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("D") > threshhold).First();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Newtonsoft.Json

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
    var rowJson = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, true);
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(rowJson);

    List<string> values = jObj["Row"]
                .Select(x => x["Cell"])
                .Where(x => x.Any(x => (string)x["Data"]["@Type"] == "Number" && (int)x["Data"]["#text"] > 200))
                .FirstOrDefault()
                //.Where(x => (string)x["Data"]["@Type"] == "Number")
                .Select(x => x["Data"]["#text"].ToString())
                .ToList();
```

result

```
["C","40","78","312"]
```

if you want to reach values separately you can use this code

```
var val0 = values[0]; // "C"
var val1 = values[1]; // "40"
// and so on
```